# Helper method to change color of alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote this little helper method:

```
def alert_color(name)
    if name == 'notice'
        return 'alert alert-dismissable alert-success'
    end
end
```

In my application layout I wrote:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div class=<%= alert_color(name) %>>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong><%= name %></strong><%= msg %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My first problem is that it somehow wont work because name isn't passed correctly to the helper_method!

And second problem is that I tried:

```
alert_color('notice')
```

and it returned this:

```
<div class="alert" alert-success="" alert-dismissable="">
```

I really don't know how to change this behavior!

And, I'm producing flash messages this way:

```
notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="<%= alert_color(name) %>">
```

Besides, you also need to code other cases out of "success" in the helper.

```
def alert_color(name)
  color = name == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'alert'
  "alert alert-dismissable alert-#{color}"
end
```

Comment: Yes this works but my first problem stays? I made an experiment and changed the helper method to `color = name == 'notice' ? 'success' : name`. So then it displays the class `alert alert-dismissable alert-notice` in my view. But netherless it wont work when in your helper method it says `name ==  'notice'` it always takes `alert` as class! I hope you understood me? How can this be?

Comment: Ok i have the solution `color = name == :notice` i had to use a symbol!Thanks again for your help and have a nice day you really helped me a lot

Comment: John, nice you figured it out. I forget flash object use symbol instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

try interpolation

```
class="#{alert_color(name)}"
```

Comment: Sorry but somehow it displays the same <div class="alert" alert-success="" alert-dismissable="">